# How to calculate the average value of following n rows based on another column - SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, range, row, average

I am trying to calculate average monthly value of premiums for each POLICY_ID in monthly basis as shown below. When a customer updates his/her yearly payment frequency to a value different than 12, I need to manually calculate the average monthly value for the PREMIUM. How can I achieve the values shown in MONTHLY _PREMIUM_DESIRED?
Thanks in advance.

Note: Oracle version 12c

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    SUM(PREMIUM) OVER(PARTITION BY T.POLICY_ID ORDER BY T.POLICY_ID, T.PAYMENT_DATE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 12/T.YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ-1 FOLLOWING ) / (12/T.YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ) MONTLY_PREMIUM_CALCULATED
FROM MYTABLE T
;
```

Code for data:

```
DROP TABLE MYTABLE;
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (POLICY_ID NUMBER(11), PAYMENT_DATE DATE, PREMIUM NUMBER(5), YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ NUMBER(2),MONTHLY_PREMIUM_DESIRED NUMBER(5));                                  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-10-01',120,12,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE  '2014-11-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2014-12-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-01-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-02-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-03-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-04-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-01',720,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-06-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-07-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-08-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-09-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-10-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1, DATE '2015-11-01',120,12,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-01-01',60,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-02-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-03-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-04-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-05-01',180,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-06-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-07-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-08-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-09-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-10-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-11-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2015-12-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-01-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-02-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-03-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-04-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-05-01',15,12,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (2, DATE '2016-06-01',15,12,15);
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
```

EDIT:

Regardless from payment frequency PREMIUM amount can also be changed by customer. Below, for the POLICY_ID = 1, I have added new records starting from "2015/11/01" to demonstrate this situation. In this case, average monthly premium increased from 120 to 240.
Also removed the screenshot to make the question more readable.

```
DROP TABLE MYTABLE2;
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE2 (POLICY_ID NUMBER(11), PAYMENT_DATE DATE, PREMIUM NUMBER(5), YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ NUMBER(2),MONTHLY_PREMIUM_DESIRED NUMBER(5));
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2014-10-01',120,12,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE  '2014-11-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2014-12-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-01-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-02-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-03-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-04-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-01',720,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-06-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-07-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-08-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-09-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-10-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-11-01',240,12,240);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-12-01',240,12,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-01-01',960,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-02-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-03-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-04-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-05-01',960,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-06-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-07-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-08-01',0,4,240);      --newly added records
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-01-01',60,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-02-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-03-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-04-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-05-01',180,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-06-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-07-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-08-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-09-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-10-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-11-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-12-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-01-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-02-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-03-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-04-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-05-01',15,12,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-06-01',15,12,15);
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE2;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Please explain the new calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the calculation is:

```
select t.*,
       premium / (12 / yearly_payment_freq)) as monthly_premium_calculated
from mytable t;
```

EDIT:

I see, you also need this spread over the intermediate months.  So you can assign the groups by counting the number of non-zero payments.  Then:

```
select t.*,
       ( max(premium) over (partition by policy_id, grp) /
         (12 / yearly_payment_freq)
       ) as monthly_premium_calculated
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when premium > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by policy_id order by payment_date) as grp
      from mytable t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cac2526e7637f0d20300ba942041bf7c) is a db<>fiddle (it uses Postgres because that is easier to set up than Oracle).

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked; however, while testing your code, I noticed that I forgot to reflect the case that the average monthly premium can be updated by customer in time. Can you please have a look at the new dataset? Thanks.

Comment: @kzmlbyrk . . . This answers the question that you *asked*.  If you have a new question, then you should ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173521/how-to-calculate-the-average-value-of-following-n-rows-based-on-another-column