# How to calculate the average value of following n rows based on another column - SQL (Oracle) - updated version of previously answered question

Tags: sql, oracle, range, row, average

I am trying to calculate average monthly value of PREMIUM for each POLICY_ID in monthly basis as shown below screenshot. When a customer updates his/her yearly PAYMENT_FREQUENCY to a value different than 12, I need to manually calculate the average monthly value for the PREMIUM. 
In addition, average monthly PREMIUM amount can be changed in time. For instance, for the POLICY_ID = 1, starting from "2015/11/01" average monthly premium increased from 120 to 240.

How can I achieve the values shown in the column named MONTHLY _PREMIUM_DESIRED?

(Early version of this question was replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171936/how-to-calculate-the-average-value-of-following-n-rows-based-on-another-column): )

Note: Oracle version 12c

[image]

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    T.*,
    SUM(PREMIUM) OVER(PARTITION BY T.POLICY_ID ORDER BY T.POLICY_ID, T.PAYMENT_DATE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 12/T.YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ-1 FOLLOWING ) / (12/T.YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ) MONTLY_PREMIUM_CALCULATED
FROM MYTABLE2 T
;
```

Codde for data:

```
DROP TABLE MYTABLE2;
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE2 (POLICY_ID NUMBER(11), PAYMENT_DATE DATE, PREMIUM NUMBER(5), YEARLY_PAYMENT_FREQ NUMBER(2),MONTHLY_PREMIUM_DESIRED NUMBER(5));
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2014-10-01',120,12,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE  '2014-11-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2014-12-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-01-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-02-01',360,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-03-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-04-01',0,4,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-05-01',720,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-06-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-07-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-08-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-09-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-10-01',0,2,120);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2015-11-01',240,12,240);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-12-01',240,12,240); 
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-01-01',960,4,240);     
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-02-01',0,4,240);   
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-03-01',0,4,240);    
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-04-01',0,4,240);  
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-05-01',960,4,240);     
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-06-01',0,4,240);     
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-07-01',0,4,240);      
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (1, DATE '2016-08-01',0,4,240);    
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-01-01',60,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-02-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-03-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-04-01',0,3,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-05-01',180,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-06-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-07-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-08-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-09-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-10-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-11-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2015-12-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-01-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-02-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-03-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-04-01',0,1,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-05-01',15,12,15);
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2 VALUES (2, DATE '2016-06-01',15,12,15);
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE2;
```

Comment: It seems to me that "average" (or "sum") is not really what you are looking to do. Instead, if premium is paid quarterly in April (say), you want to allocate the payment to three months, April, May, June, one third each. Right? For that, it makes no sense to involve any data for July or August in the computation - which is what you are doing in the analytic function.

Comment: OK, now: If this is your requirement - is it guaranteed that the data is internally consistent? So, for example, if a "quarterly" payment is make in July, then the rows for August and September for that policy will still show "quarterly" frequency (and perhaps premium paid of "zero")? If so, it would make more sense if the table didn't even show the rows with "zero" payment - just the months with payments, and assumed frequency. (The data would still have to be internally consistent even then, though.)

Comment: And as an aside - it never makes sense to have the same expression in `PARTITION BY` and in `ORDER BY` of an analytic function. You don't need POLICY_ID in the ORDER BY clause of your analytic sum - it's constant within each partition anyway, so it contributes nothing to the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is this:

```
select t.*, 
       last_value(nullif(premium * yearly_payment_freq / 12, 0) ignore nulls) 
                   over (partition by policy_id order by payment_date)
                   as monthly_premium_calculated
from   mytable2 t
;
```

For a month with a non-zero payment, this takes the premium paid, it multiplies by the annual frequency to get an equivalent annual premium, and it divides the result by 12 to get a monthly equivalent. For a month where the premium is zero, the assumption is that that month's premium was paid in an earlier month (with a frequency less than "monthly" - that is, the premium was paid for a full quarter, or half-year, or year).

Running this on your data I found a mistake in your "desired" data. For POLICY_ID = 1, for '2016-01-01', you show payment of 960 and annual frequency of 4, and "desired monthly amount" of 240. Isn't that wrong? Frequency of 4 means "quarterly", and if the quarterly amount is 960, then the monthly amount is 320, not 240. Right? My computation gets the result 320.

There is also a typo in your inputs: you have a row for December 2016 for policy id 1, when you meant December 2015. I meant to edit your post to correct that, but then I realized the image you posted is based on the wrong data (with that typo). If I only change it in the `INSERT` statements, then they won't match the image...

Comment: @ mathguy, thanks for your answer and also for the corrections!